# How to move MUI DataGrid Pagination table to the left side using CustomPagination

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello guys I am tring to better understand MUI data grid, and to fufill a design specification for a table view I am using DataGrid from MUI for the pagination I am using their custom implementation but I can't find out how to manipulated it to change places since the CustomPagination is being overriten by the root of the DataGrid, I am gonna share the CodeSandbox from MUI for the Custom implementation and what I am trying to achive.

codesanbox demo => https://codesandbox.io/s/ybuq4n?file=/demo.tsx
searched result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHKWh.png)

I have tried searching on documentation about that but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily by substituting the footer with the pagination component. Be aware that if you do this you loose the "rows selected" count... As the free DataGrid doesn't have the ability to select more than one row, that really shouldn't matter anyway...

If you want more functionality in your footer, you quite simply build your pagination into a custom footer.
If you do that you can also control what you want left and right by using css.

```js
    return (
        <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
          <DataGrid
            pagination
            pageSize={5}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
            components={{
              Footer: CustomPagination,
            }}
            {...data}
          />
        </Box>
      );
```

Comment: It is possible to select multiple rows within the DataGrid. [Multiple Row Selection](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-selection/#multiple-row-selection)

Although, it is worth pointing out that it is not part of the free version.

Comment: @McBurd Thank you for pointing that out. I edited a bit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to pass down an alignment to the footer of the MUI DataGrid. So you need to make a custom footer and re-arrange the default ordering of the footer components. So your code will need to look something like this.

DataGrid usage:
If you are using a more recent version of MUI data grid, use the slots prop instead of components, it is deprecated.

```
 <DataGrid
    pagination
    pageSize={5}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
    components={{
      Footer: CustomFooter,
    }}
    {...data}
  />
```

Custom Footer:
You need to make sure that your custom pagination falls first within the the GridFooterContainer. The components will be
generated in the html from top to bottom, and therefore, will appear from left-to-right.

```
const CustomFooter = () => {
    
    const gridApi = useGridApiContext();
    
    return (
        <GridFooterContainer>
            <CustomPagination />
            {
                !!gridApi.current.getSelectedRows().size && 
                    <GridSelectedRowCount selectedRowCount={gridApi.current.getSelectedRows().size} />
            }
        </GridFooterContainer>
    );
};

export default CustomFooter;
```

Hope this helps.